# How to parse and form a json with a nested array?

Tags: javascript, json

I need advice and help.
I have a code with which I receive data from the table in json format, so that I can then send it via ajax to the server

```
for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    let docDate = document.querySelector('input[name="invoice-date"]').value
    let docContragent = document.querySelector('select').value
    // ITEMS
    let name = row.cells[1].querySelector('span').dataset.id
    let quantity = row.cells[2].querySelector('input').value
    let buy_price = row.cells[3].querySelector('input').value
    var sell_price = row.cells[5].querySelector('input').value

    if(row == document.querySelector('.add-elements')) {
      break;
    }
   let invoice = {
    "doc_type": "capitalize",
    "date": docDate,
    "number": 98,
    "contragent_id": docContragent,
    "comment": "",
    "items": [
        {
            "product": name,
            "buy_price": buy_price,
            "sell_price": sell_price,
            "quantity": quantity
          },
        ]
      }
      let json = JSON.stringify(invoice);
      console.log(json)
    }
```

The problem is that there can be any number of elements in the "items" array (rows in the table) and I don't know how to implement this in javascript. And how safe is it?
Maybe you know the best option for sending such data, I work with django (the only possible solution I found there was to use form sets, but it seems to me that this option will not work because of its limited customization).

I need this json output:

```
[
    {
        "doc_type": "capitalize",
        "date": "2022-06-04",
        "number": 1,
        "contragent_id" : 1,
        "comment": "",
        "items": [
            {
                "product": 10,
                "buy_price": "200.00",
                "sell_price": "500.00",
                "quantity": 5
            },
            {
                ...
            },
            {
                ...
            },
        ],
    }
]
```

The HTML of the table is added dynamically via api, with this code:

```
success: function (res) {
          let invoiceRow = document.querySelector(".invoice-add-table table tbody tr.add-elements").insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<tr class="invoice-row">' +
          '<td align="right" class="fixed">'+ res.articul +'</td>' +
          '<td class="name" align="left"><span data-id="'+ res.id +'" title="'+ res.name +'" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;">'+ res.name +'</span></td>' +
          '<td align="right" class="fixed"><input name="quantity" value="'+ 1 +'" class="ta-right fixed" onkeypress="validateNum(event)" type="number"></td>' +
          '<td align="right" class="fixed"><input name="last_buy_price" value="'+ res.last_buy_price +'" class="ta-right fixed" onkeypress="validateNumFloat(event)" type="number"></td>' +
          '<td align="right" class="fixed"><input name="summ" value="" class="ta-right fixed" onkeypress="validateNumFloat(event)" type="number"></td>' +
          '<td align="right" class="fixed"><input name="sell_price" value="'+ res.sell_price +'" class="ta-right fixed" onkeypress="validateNumFloat(event)" type="number"></td>' +
          '<td align="right"><div style="display: flex;" class="edit-tool-table"><span class="iconify" onclick="test()" data-icon="bx:trash" style="color: white;" data-width="20"></span></div></td>'+
          '</tr>');
        },
```

P. s I'm sorry if there are errors in the text, I write it through google translate)

Comment: Please provide the HTML which this code is reading. Also, your code has more closing braces than opening, and `docContragent` is never used.

Comment: The HTML of the table is added dynamically, I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop will fill your array with all items and at the end push array with all items on your json

```
let items = [];
let docDate;

for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    if(row == document.querySelector('.add-elements')) {
      break;
    }
    docDate = document.querySelector('input[name="invoice-date"]').value
    let docContragent = document.querySelector('select').value
    // ITEMS
    let name = row.cells[1].querySelector('span').dataset.id
    let quantity = row.cells[2].querySelector('input').value
    let buy_price = row.cells[3].querySelector('input').value
    var sell_price = row.cells[5].querySelector('input').value

    items.push({
        "product": name,
        "buy_price": buy_price,
        "sell_price": sell_price,
        "quantity": quantity
    });
}

let invoice = {
    "doc_type": "capitalize",
    "date": docDate,
    "number": 98,
    "comment": "",
    "items": items
}
let json = JSON.stringify(invoice);
console.log(json)
```

Comment: I pasted this into a function, now the console has this error on this line "items.append({": TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...items.append...')

Comment: My bad in JS `.append` doesn't exist use : `.push`

Comment: I don't understand why this is also wrong: "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'row.cells[2].querySelector('input').value')"

Comment: I managed to fix it, I edited your answer, thanks a lot